# Get full day Name from DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have js calender when I select date from calender it calls C# service  which takes string as parameter . It is getting date in format Mon Apr 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT 0500 . I want Monday intead of Mon.

My java Script code is

```
$scope.deliveryDateTime = {  Day: new Date(2015, 11, 28, 14, 57) };
 var DeliveryDay =  $scope.deliveryDateTimeData.Day;

        $http.get(meta.service.GetTimeAvlb+'?day='+ DeliveryDay).
           success(function (data) {
               debugger;
               console.log("Data" + data);
               $scope.AvailiableTimeData = data.data;                  
               }                 
           }).
           error(function (data) {
           });
```

Here is my C# Service code

```
public ApiResult GetTimeAvlb( string day )
     {                    
        var splitDay = day.Split(' ');
        string dayName1 = splitDay[0].ToString();            
        apiresilt.data = db.TimeAvaliblities.Where(ss => ss.DayName == dayName1).ToList();
        return apiresilt;
     }
```

here dayName1 returning Mon while my db has value Monday .

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* wanna parse this `string` to `DateTime`, you *have to* use your `GMT 0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)` part as a string literal. DateTime parsing methods does not support timezone names and UTC Offset part *without* [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator).

Then you can use [`DateTime.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with [`dddd` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddddSpecifier) and *english-based* culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).

```
var s = "Mon Apr 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT 0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT 0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)'",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dddd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

By the way, there is no such a thing as *date time string*. Your data either can be `DateTime` or `string`.

Comment: Great explanation even for such simple things, brilliant[+]

Answer (score 2):

[`.ToString("Format-String")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)  can be used for display date in required format;

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; will be the current date APR/01/2016
string str = dt.ToString("dddd"); // this will be Friday for 04/01/2016
```

Comment: The full list of format strings available can be found here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "// this will be Friday" ... not always ... have a nice weekend! (upvoted).

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith : I think i have added the same link in the answer. have you checked that before commenting?

Comment: @Gustav : great , i have included the date in comment

Comment: @un-lucky Yes I did and I'm sorry but when I posted this link was not there.  You edited while I was posting and this link/update appeared then after I had just posted.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith : it's ok thank you for that valuable point;